# Second for loop not running

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

I'm using Apache POI to read and write to excel files. However, while trying to write to two different sheets in 1 workbook, my second for loop is not executing. Therefore, only the first worksheet is written to while the second worksheet is not.

```
for (int r = 4; r < outTotalRows1; r++) {
    row2 = outSheet1.getRow(r);
    if (row2.getCell(3) == null) {
        for (int t = 3; t <= 47; t++) {
            outCell = row2.createCell(t);
            outCell.setCellValue(BSMeanArray[t - 3]);
            FileOutputStream outWrite = new FileOutputStream(new File(outputFileName));
            outWorkbook.write(outWrite);
            outWrite.close();
        }
    }
    if (row2.getCell(50) == null) { // if the velocity cell is == null, then set cell value to array established and then break
        for (int u = 50; u < 94; u++) {
            outCell = row2.createCell(u); // maybe this line wrong?
            outCell.setCellValue(BFMeanArray[u - 50]);
            FileOutputStream outWrite = new FileOutputStream(new File(outputFileName));
            outWorkbook.write(outWrite);
            outWrite.close();
        }
    }
}

// THIS LOOP NOT EXECUTING
for(int r = 4; r < outTotalRows2; r++){
    System.out.println("executed");
    row3 = outSheet2.getRow(r);
    if (row3.getCell(3) == null) {
        for (int u = 3; u <= 47; u++) {
            outCell = row3.createCell(u);
            outCell.setCellValue(FFSMeanArray[u - 3]);
            FileOutputStream outWrite = new FileOutputStream(new File(outputFileName));
            outWorkbook.write(outWrite);
            outWrite.close();
        }
    }
    if (row3.getCell(50) == null) {
        for (int u = 50; u <= 94; u++) {
            outCell = row3.createCell(u);
            outCell.setCellValue(FFFMeanArray[u - 50]);
            FileOutputStream outWrite = new FileOutputStream(new File(outputFileName));
            outWorkbook.write(outWrite);
            outWrite.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? What's the value of `outTotalRows2`?

Comment: Only way I see from here is, that the condition `outTotalRows2` is incorrect. Are you sure the value of the variable is stored correctly?

Comment: Insert this right above your second loop if you don't know how to debug. `System.out.println(outTotalRows2)`

Comment: might be that your outputFileName never changes, so it tries to overwrite the first one, and finds that it is not allowed to do that. So the loop would be executing, and only the output step fails.

Comment: I'm certain my outTotalRows2 is correct.

`int outTotalRows1 = outSheet1.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();  
int outTotalRows2 = outSheet2.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();`

where 

`Sheet outSheet1 = outWorkbook.getSheetAt(0);
 
Sheet outSheet2 = outWorkbook.getSheetAt(1);`

Comment: @DavisBroda

I thought about that, but the `System.out.println("executed");` in the second loop never executes

Comment: first of all one suggestion is that... try to perform write excel at the very end of your  code... very end means it should be called **ONLY** once... not more than once... As while performing `outwrite.close`. it releases all of this resource. Try this once and share your outcomes.